# How to print the first object in the multidimensional array (forelse loop) in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop

I Want to Display just the first object (location in my case).

```
    @forelse($locations as $key => $value)
```

I tried this:

```
<?php
     @forelse($locations as $key => $value) {
       $value = $locations->first();
    }
?>
```

it gives a syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS), expecting ')'

```
    $result = $query->get();

    $locations = $result->pluck('name', 'id');

    $price_groups = SellingPriceGroup::forDropdown($business_id);

    if ($show_all) {
        $locations->prepend(__('report.all_locations'), '');
    }
```

ack.imgur.com/avYXn.png

Comment: are you mixing Blade syntax with raw php?

Comment: I'm new to Blade Syntax, so any help with the issue will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $loop variable like. It should be:

```
@forelse ($locations as $key => $value)
  @if ($loop->first)
  //this is the first iteration.
  @endif
@empty
  //Logic when the array is empty
@endforelse
```

Check the doc: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#loops

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH), expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF) 

 `<?php endforeach; $__env->popLoop(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); if ($__empty_1): ?>
        <?php endif; ?>`

Comment: My bad. There is a "@empty" when using the "@forelse" loop. Just corrected it. But why don't you just use the "@foreach" ? May your array be empty ?